# objective c - copy files into existing directory

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsfilemanager

How do I copy files from DIR1 to DIR2 , without copying the entire directory?

I'm trying to copy files to a folder that contains other files, so I don't want to create a new folder. which what the following code does:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourceDir toPath:destDir error:&err];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the contents in the folder

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
```

Enumerate over the files list and copy them.

```
[fileList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *string, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:&Error];
}];
```

Comment: `directoryContentsAtPath:` is deprecated. Use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` instead.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I've done it:

```
NSArray *sourceFiles = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourceDir error:NULL];

NSError *copyError = nil;

for (NSString *currentFile in sourceFiles)
{
    BOOL isDirectory = NO;
    NSString* fullFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",sourceDir,currentFile];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullFilePath isDirectory:&isDirectory] && !isDirectory)
    {
        if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:[sourceDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFile] toPath:[destDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFile] error:&copyError])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error Copying: %@", [copyError description]);
        }
    }
}
```